# FileZilla - Update local files, but not write new files

Tags: ftp, filezilla

Is there a function in FileZilla or in any other ftp client, to update all local files and subfolders of a selected folder from remote ones, without write any new file or folder that is present in remote but not locally?

I'm a developer and I have to keep up to date my files, but I don't want to download data files, logs, images and any other file that I don't need to write code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that FileZilla cannot do this.

You can only explicitly list the files/folders that you do not want to transfer.

---

As an alternative, you can use [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/).

Its [*Synchronization* function](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_synchronize) has *"Existing files only"* option.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: Is WinSCP available for OSX too?

Comment: No it's not. It's Windows only. You can run it under Wine though.